# Communication between 2 server

Tags: sql-server

I have two server. One with sql server and another with dbf. 
I would like to access form MSSQL server to dbf server.
But i haven't access to this server. How can i managed that?

Thanks

Julien

Comment: Which server don't you have access to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it is possible to link these servers together, I would suspect not. So, here's how I would accomplish what you are asking.

In VB.NET or C#:

**Step 1** - Query both databases

Query both databases and dump the data from each database into two separate datatables.

**Step 2** - Combine and/or process the data

Depending on your requirements, loop through data from each database and combine the data into a third datatable or process the as data as necessary

**Step 3** - Write the results

Now, depending on your requirements, you can write data back to both databases (one at a time, each using a different database connection)

Comment: It's what i do now.
I use Linq to join my two server.

Thanks

Julien